# Extracting and saving data from a browser presentation, automatically, once a minute, from a device on a local network

Tags: http, ftp, vb6

I have a device (an "ESBox") next to my modem that sends data on my house power to a government backed website that now doesn't exist. The device requires a username and password, and displays updates about every six seconds. All I want to do, is get to this data, not the HTML presenting the info.
I created a VB6 program a decade ago, to look at another device which also does a similar job (3 phase monitoring of house power, sent by a transmitter to a receiver that connects to a USB port on my computer, but the data cross-modulates within the transmitter, corrupting the accuracy)

All I want to do is get to this ESBox data, via VB6, so I can re-write my original program, because the accuracy is incredible, about 1 percent, and bi-directional, which the other system isn't.
I've been searching the internet, tried a few examples, but nothing seems to work. All these programs return the HTML coding, and not the data.

As an example, if I put "esbox:esbox@esbox/api/devices" into Firefox, I get the data, but if I put the same thing into a VB control or reference, I get the HTML coding for the screen, not the data!!
Frustrating. How do I get to the data underlying the screen on my browser, and not the screen presentation?

I've used the VB Inet control, the Winsocket, the Wininet dll, but nothing appears to work. for example

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
  ` Download the file.

   URLDownloadToFile 0, "http://esbox:esbox@esbox/api/devices", "e:\esbox\esbox5\devices.txt", 0, 0

   rtBox.LoadFile ("e:\esbox\esbox5\devices.txt")

End Sub
```

Entering "http://esbox:esbox@esbox/api/devices" into Firefox displays the data, running the above program just displays the HTML code

Changing the above using ftp just hangs the program

A lot of the code I've come across, and tried, is very similar to this - some is simple as above, and some with a lot of complexity.
But everything I've tried returns the HTML coding, not the data underlying the screen display.
What am I missing? something simple, for sure

Comment: There may be a more direct method, but in the past I've "scraped" data from a web page  by getting the HTML-formatted data into a string (string length in VB6 is limited only be memory), then parsing that string to extract the desired data from it.  As long as the format of the data doesn't change, which it sounds like it won't in this case, this has been very reliable.  There may be performance considerations if the data is large, but these would likely be offset by the speed of current hardware, and that the program can be compiled, not interpreted as for example a Python solution would be.

Comment: I'm curious - are you getting the actual data or is the HTML for like a login page where you enter username/password?  It may just be a matter of making the call twice - once to get authenticated and the next call to get the raw data.

Comment: You're right, Jimmy, in Firefox, (or any other browser), the first 'request' responds with an opening screen. asking for username/password, then any subsequent request opens the screen showing a list of devices, updated every six seconds with info.

Comment: bugger, I hit the 'Enter' key. That's great if I want to spend all day in front of a computer, watching the phase data change, but what I want is an automatic way to extract this data about once a minute, without having to see it. That's my frustration - I can see this data changing in a browser, but I haven't found a way to extract it without having to open a browser, if you get what I'm asking